# How to keep track of Runnables in Thread Pool in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I am using a Map of Threads and associated runnable object to keep track of runnables. The purpose behind this when `interruptedException` is thrown, i want to access the current thread and its runnable object.

```
Map<Thread, Runnable> myMap = new Map<Thread, Runnable>();
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
pool.execute(new myRunnable());
```

But when i am adding the runnable to the thread pool, i can not think of a way to fill the Map.

How do i add the an entry to the map containing Thread and its runnable object?

Comment: Your goal is not clear. When the executing thead is interrupted, you can access the interruption flag from within that thread (i.e. from your runnable).

Comment: I have to access a method defined in runnable object once the thread is interrupted. Your suggestion is helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're approaching it from the wrong angle.  Once you submit to the thread you should be under the impression that your work is done.  Any interruption that occurs should be handled by the executing thread.

For instance

```
public void run(){
    try{
      //do some work that responds to interruption
    }catch(InterruptedException ex){
       //clean up
    }
}
```

Or

```
public void run(){
    if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrtuped()){
        //clean up
        return;
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use ThreadPoolExecutor's hook methods:

```
    final Map<Runnable, Thread> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Runable, Thread>();
    ExecutorService pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()) {
        @Override
        protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
            map.put(r, t);
        }

        @Override
        protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
            map.remove(r);
        }
    };
```

Comment: @Evgeniy Dorofeev if you were to do this, you should not use a `HashMap`.  The method `afterExecute` is being called from the invoking thread meaning concurrent modifications

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind ExecutorService is to abstract away from the threads being used. You could override myRunnable to leak the information.

So you would call

```
pool.execute(new myRunnable(myMap));
```

and then in myRunnable have the constructor save the reference to myMap and add

```
myMap.put(this,originalRunnableObject)
```

to the run method - where originalRunnableObject is a saved reference to this. Of course you would need your map to be a concurrent map (you can't instantiate the Map interface as you're trying to do).

However, one has to ask why you want to do this in the first place, as I said an Executor is supposed to give a layer of abstraction which you appear to want to subvert.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Map might cause concurrent modifications, Queue may be a better choice.
    final BlockingQueue<Pair<Thread, Runnable>> interruptedRunnable = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>(0);
    threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // TODO do something here?

                if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                    interruptedRunnable.add(Pair.of(Thread.currentThread(), this));
                    return;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException _) {
                interruptedRunnable.add(Pair.of(Thread.currentThread(), this));
            }
        }
    });

    // TODO polling ...
    while (true) {
        try {

            // TODO adjust timeout
            Pair<Thread, Runnable> x = interruptedRunnable.poll(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

            if (null != x) {
                // check x.
            }
            // TODO
        } catch (InterruptedException _) {
         break;   
        }
    }
```